# Xamarin android, how to make tabpage icon bigger

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin.android.

Build a tabbed page. And use an icon as each sheet's title as below.

But the image is much small then the area.

Is it possible to make it bigger?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Build a tabbed page. And use an icon as each sheet's title as below.But the image is much small then the area.Is it possible to make it bigger?

If you want to make the TabbedPage icon to bigger, you have to make a custom renderer to achieve it.

Firstly, create  a custom renderer `MyTabbedPageRenderer.cs` in Android platform.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(MyTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace FormsSample.Droid
{
public class MyTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
{
    public MyTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    protected override void SetTabIcon(TabLayout.Tab tab, FileImageSource icon)
    {
        base.SetTabIcon(tab, icon);
        tab.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.Custom_tab_layou);

        var imageview = tab.CustomView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.icon);

        var textview = tab.CustomView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv);
        textview.Text = tab.Text;

        imageview.SetBackgroundDrawable(tab.Icon);

    }
}
}
```

Then create custom tab for TabbedPage tab, add ImageView and TevtView to display icon and title for TabbedPage. You can make ImageView layout_height bigger to display icon.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"       
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="11dp"
    android:textColor="#00FF6F" />
```

This is the screenshot:

[image]

The Tabbedpage:

```
<TabbedPage
x:Class="FormsSample.tabbedpage.TabbedPage5"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
<!--  Pages can be added as references or inline  -->
<ContentPage Title="Tab 1" IconImageSource="favorite.png" />
<ContentPage Title="Tab 2" IconImageSource="check.png" />
<ContentPage Title="Tab 3" IconImageSource="flag.png" />
```